# Removing blank spaces and tabs from line without messing with line endings

Tags: command-line, files

I am trying to remove all spaces on a file without messing with line endings. This is to be run from inside a bash script.

I have tried all the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953448/how-to-remove-all-white-spaces-from-a-given-text-file

They work from the command line but when I try them from the bash script the final file is a mess, completely destroyed.

File is using UNIX file endings.

Any clues?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use `tr`, but not as specified on the page your link points to as that includes the removal of newline and carriage return. What you should do is:

```
tr -d " \t" < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: I have tried that before without success. For some reason, worked now... thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the `[[:blank:]]` character class to `tr` to delete spaces and tabs but retain newlines

```
<file tr -d '[[:blank:]]'
```